# weighted IV estimation by plm

Tags: fixed-effects-model, instrumental-variables, weighted-regression, plm

I apply plm package to do fixed effects IV regression but find something which I couldn't understand.

Theoretically, if we only have one endogenous variable and one IV, the IV estimator should be equal to cov(Y,Z|X)/cov(T,Z|X), in which Z is the IV, T is the endogenous treatment, X is control variables (include fixed effects). For some reasons, I use a vector which refers to weights.
To check the first stage, I regress T on Z and X. And then I also regress Y on Z and X. Theoretically, the ratio of the coefficients from the two regressions should be equal to the one from IV regression.

The interesting issue is that if I apply the weights into IV regression and two fixed regression (Y on Z X and T on Z X). I find the ratio of the coefficients from the two regressions is not equal to the one from IV regression. However, they are equal without weights.

Can anyone explain the reason? Is there something wrong in the plm package?

Answer (score 1):

`plm` does not yet support the `weights` argument for panel IV estimations, see the error message given by the latest CRAN version (1.7-0):

```
library(plm)
data(Grunfeld)
plm(inv ~ value + capital | value + capital, data = Grunfeld, weights = 1:200)
#> Error in plm.fit(formula, data, model, effect, random.method, random.models, : 
argument 'weights' not yet implemented for instrumental variable models
```